# PHP file not receiving $_POST

Tags: c#, php, validation

I'm having a problem with my C# code, which posts data from a login form to be validated on a PHP page.

On my development page, it works fine, but when I switch over to the production page, it stops working. (Both web pages are located on the same server).

My login page (development) looks like this:

```
$user = DB_Login($_POST["username"], $_POST["password"]);
if (!is_null($user))
{
SetLoginCookies($user["userID"], $user["sessionID"]);
echo "valid";
}
else
echo "invalid";
```

and my production page looks like this:

```
$responseArray = DB_Login($_POST["username"], $_POST["password"]);

if (is_null($responseArray))
{
    die("invalid");
}
```

It's pretty similar, but I don't get why my production page never receives POST variables, it always dies.

My C# code (which either of the pages) looks like this:

```
private void Login_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string sendData = "";
        Uri site = new Uri("site");
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        sendData += "username=" + usrname.Text;
        sendData += "&password=" + pword.Password;
        wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentLength] = sendData.Length.ToString();
        wc.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_UploadStringCompleted);
        wc.UploadStringAsync(site, "POST", sendData);
    }

    private void wc_UploadStringCompleted(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Result.Equals("invalid"))
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Result.ToString());

            //Navigate to next page
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/ControlPanel.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
    }
```

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

the DB_Login function looks like this:

```
function DB_Login($username, $password)
{
$password = md5($password);
$username = mysql_escape_string($username);

$request = DB_ExecuteQuery("SELECT userID, isAdmin
    FROM accounts
    WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'");
if ($request->num_rows == 0)
    return NULL;

$requestArray = $request->fetch_array();

$response = array("userID" => $requestArray["userID"]);
$response["sessionID"] = mysql_escape_string(generateGuid());
$response["isAdmin"] = $requestArray["isAdmin"];

DB_ExecuteQuery("UPDATE accounts
    SET sessionID = '". $response['sessionID'] ."'
    WHERE userID = ". $response['userID']);

DB_SetLastLogin($requestArray['userID']);

return $response;
}
```

the result of var_dump($_POST["username"], $_POST["password"]) is NULL and NULL.

update 2:

result of $print_r($_SERVER):

```
Array (
  [SCRIPT_URL] => /phone/windowsphone/driverDetails.php
  [SCRIPT_URI] => https://www.xxxxx.com/phone/windowsphone/driverDetails.php 
  [MvCONFIG_FLAGS_SECURITY] => 15
  [MvCONFIG_DIR_MIVA] => /home/sites/home/miva
  [MvCONFIG_DIR_DATA] => /home/sites/home/mivadata
  [MvCONFIG_DIR_BUILTIN] => /home/miva/builtins
  [MvCONFIG_DIR_CA] => /home/miva/certs
  [MvCONFIG_DIR_BUILTIN] => /home/miva/builtins
  [MvCONFIG_DIR_CA] => /home/miva/certs
  [MvCONFIG_SSL_CRYPTO] => /lib/libcrypto.so.4
  [MvCONFIG_SSL_OPENSSL] => /lib/libssl.so.4
  [MvCONFIG_DATABASE_MivaSQL] => /home/miva/databases/mivasql.so
  [MvCONFIG_DATABASE_mysql] => /home/miva/databases/mysql.so
  [MvCONFIG_COMMERCE_AuthorizeNet] => /home/miva/commerce/authnet-v5.06-linux_glibc2.so
  [MvCONFIG_COMMERCE_CyberCash] => /home/miva/commerce/cybercash_de-v5.03-linux_glibc2.so
  [MvCONFIG_COMMERCE_ICS2] => /home/miva/commerce/ics2-v5.06-linux_glibc2.so
  [MvCONFIG_COMMERCE_LinkPoint] => /home/miva/commerce/linkpoint-v5.06-linux_glibc2.so
  [MvCONFIG_COMMERCE_UPSRSS] => /home/miva/commerce/upsrss-v5.03-linux_glibc2.so
  [MvCONFIG_LIBRARY] => /home/miva/config/env.so
  [HTTPS] => on
  [HTTP_HOST] => www.xxxxx.com
  [HTTP_CONNECTION] => keep-alive
  [HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL] => max-age=0
  [HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.57 Safari/536.11
  [HTTP_ACCEPT] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
  [HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip,deflate,sdch
  [HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE] => en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
  [HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET] => ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
  [HTTP_COOKIE] => ow-autologin=0; ow-loginname=whaxi; ow-default_logindomain=www.xxxxx.com; ow-httpcompress=1
  [PATH] => /sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
  [SERVER_SIGNATURE] => Apache Server at www.xxxxx.com Port 443
  [SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache
  [SERVER_NAME] => www.xxxxx.com
  [SERVER_ADDR] => 11.22.33.44
  [SERVER_PORT] => 443
  [REMOTE_ADDR] => 44.33.22.11
  [DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /home/.sites/28/site1/web
  [SERVER_ADMIN] => admin
  [SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /home/.sites/28/site1/web/phone/windowsphone/driverDetails.php
  [REMOTE_PORT] => 16199
  [GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
  [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1
  [REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
  [QUERY_STRING] =>
  [REQUEST_URI] => /phone/windowsphone/driverDetails.php
  [SCRIPT_NAME] => /phone/windowsphone/driverDetails.php
  [PHP_SELF] => /phone/windowsphone/driverDetails.php
  [REQUEST_TIME] => 1343076397
  [argv] => Array ( )
  [argc] => 0
)
```

Comment: Just a comment: `$var === NULL` is much faster and more efficient than `is_null($var)`. We're talking microseconds, but still worth noting. Can we see your `DB_Login()` function? Also, what does `var_dump($_POST["username"], $_POST["password"]);` show?

Comment: does `isset($_POST)` return true? if so try `var_dump($_POST)` to check its contents

Comment: @optimusprime619 `isset($_POST)` (I think) always returns true - you want to check `!empty($_POST)` instead

Comment: @DaveRandom okay, the property being global always exists and need not be `NULL` , then `!empty($_POST)` it is.. thanks for spotting

Comment: alright, i'll update my question with the results of the var_dump and everything

Comment: @docaholic OK if you are getting `NULL NULL` from the `var_dump()` then problem really is that the POST variables are not making in into your script. Can you show `print_r($_SERVER);` please?

Comment: okay i updated again, with the results of $print_r

Comment: @docaholic OK there's your problem: `[REQUEST_METHOD] => GET` - for some reason your request is coming through to your script as a `GET` request. I'm wondering if it's being redirected? I would have a look in the access logs to see if you can see a `POST` request that is being redirected. What is the URL of your dev and live locations? You can blank out the hostname portion if you like, it's the path components I'm interested in.

Comment: hmm okay the dev location is this:

https://www.xxxxx.com/m/dat/login.php;

the live location is:

https://www.xxxxx.com/phone/windowsphone/driverDetails.php

Comment: what i don't get is, if the [REQUEST METHOD] =>GET, then how come the other page (which uses POST) works correctly?

Comment: @docaholic If you are pointing directly to PHP scripts then I can't see any reason for this, it is very odd indeed. So you're saying that if you switch back to the dev site, it works? I can't see anything in the code on either side the would cause the request method to change, I was wondering if you were requesting a directory without a trailing slash  and this was causing Apache to issue a redirect with for some reason was causing the request method to change, but this doesn't seem to be the case. Can you do a `print_r($_SERVER)` on the dev page?

Comment: @docaholic Also can you look at your Apache access logs and see what appears when you make a request (to the production site)?

Comment: the print_r($_SERVER) on the dev page looks exactly like the one from the live page ([REQUEST METHOD] => GET) except for the urls obviously....so i'm terribly confused

Comment: @docaholic I've just been throwing a few requests at your server (as you did leave the full URI in your original post, apologies if you're not comfortable with this but I assure you all my activity has been purely benevolent) and I can't "break" it - although obviously I don't have a valid username and password to get any response other than `invalid`. One thing I can say is my POST requests are not getting redirected anywhere and turned into GETs - so I'm leaning towards this being a problem somewhere in the C#. Although I can't see it.

Comment: Hmm okay alright, I'll go recheck my C# and see what happens. Thanks for your help!

Comment: okay! i think i solved my problem. The issue here (i found) was the fact that I was creating an XML document inside live PHP file (i never showed that part of the code). Once I removed it (and moved the xml generation to another file), everything works as planned! Thanks for everybody's help!

Answer (score 1):

```
UploadStringAsync
```

function send string as RAW data, it cant see in $_POST array
In, php code use

```
file_get_contents('php://input')
```

to receive that, or in C# use

```
NameValueCollection reqparm = new NameValueCollection();
reqparm.Add("username", "asd");
reqparm.Add("pass", "smthg");
...
wc.UploadValues(this.url, "POST", this.reqparm);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I think you should get the POST method in the headers, instead you are getting the GET method.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking for

```
method="post"
```

in your `<form>` tag, or whatever. If you see something like ...

```
method="get"
```

... that's your problem. Change the method to post.